# Flash CS5 Publish Website Problems

Tags: flash

I just got Flash CS5 and I finally finished my website layout. But after publishing it and uploading it online, my browser says I don't have the newest version of flash and that I need to install it. Since I know that I have the most recent version (Flash Player 10), I don't understand why my website won't show.

Do you guys know this sort of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant javascript code that detects the version of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Something was wrong the the html file that flash published.
I just did it myself in dreamweaver and now it works ;)

Thanks anyway!